# Find bases of given subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let
$U = \{x ∈ R^5 : x_1 + x_3 + x_4 = 0, 2x_1 + 2x_2 + x_5 = 0\}, W = \{x ∈ R^5: x_1 + x_5 = 0, x_2 = x_3 = x_4\}.$

Find bases for U and W containing a basis for $U ∩ W$ as a subset.

Give a basis for $U + W$ and show that 
$U + W = \{x ∈ R^5 : x_1 + 2x_2 + x_5 = x_3 + x_4\}.$

I learn linear algebra and got stuck with understanding of question 'containing a basis for U ∩ W as a subset'. How should it be solved? Also, I will be grateful if you provide some hints how to solve the second part too.

I have found basis for U is

$x_5 = -2x_1 - 2x_2$

$x_4 = -x_1 - x_3$

$x_1(1, 0, 0, -1, -2) + x_2(0, 1, 0, 0, -2) + x_3(0, 0, 1, -1, 0) = 0$

The basis for W is

$x_5 = -x_1$

$x_1(1, 0, 0, 0, -1) + x_2(0, 1, 1, 1, 0) = 0$

Finding the intersection of U and W:
x from W will be renamed to $x_4$ and $x_5$

$x_1(1, 0, 0, -1, -2) + x_2(0, 1, 0, 0, -2) + x_3(0, 0, 1, -1, 0) = x_4(1, 0, 0, 0, -1) + x_5(0, 1, 1, 1, 0)$

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\ -2 & -2 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow 
 \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

The columns of this matrix indicate the basis of the intersection.
The basis for U containing the intersection will be $\{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5\}$
And what about W? Is it same?
Is it correct answer to the first part of question about the intersection?

Comment: The elements of the intersection satisfy all 4 equations. Find a basis for it, and extend that for both $U$ and $W$.

Comment: @Berci Should I assume that $x_i$ from equations in U and $x_i$ from equations in W are same?

Answer (score 1):

$x_1,\dots, x_5$ are variables for real numbers, they are not a (part of any) basis.

A vector ${\bf x} =(x_1,\dots, x_5)\in\Bbb R^5$ is in $U$ iff its coordinates (i.e. the numbers $x_1,\dots,x_5$) satisfy the defining equations. Similarly for $W$. 
So, ${\bf x}\in U\cap W$ iff its coordinates satisfy all the  given equations at once.

Your method to find a basis is correct, but as result, you wrote up a generic linear composition of the basis elements instead of simply listing them (without any $x_i$).

> You will find that the single vector $(-2,1,1,1,2)$ is a basis for $U\cap W$.

Extend this to a basis in both $U$ and $W$, and take the union of these to obtain a basis for $U+W$.